# bash - Conditional for filtering on string '15m' or less

Tags: bash

I'm checking the age of an object, and it gives me one of the following types of outputs, e.g: 30s, 15m, 3h, 17d.  (meaning 30 seconds, 15 minutes, 3 hours, 17 days, respectfully)

Each of these is just a simple string.

What's the best way to say: "if under 15m, continue, else break"?

I can only think of

`if 's' or 'm' not in 'string' then break`

`if 'm' in 'string' and '2-digits-preceding-m' > 15 then break`

Is there a more elegant way of doing this, possibly in which I can turn these values into actual timestamps to compare more robustly?

Comment: Have you checked that the tool that provides you with an age doesn't have a way to produce it in number of seconds? That's often provided in order to simplify exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: If there isn't, what you propose is perfectly acceptable. You could use a regex to check it in one go, but while it would be more concise there wouldn't be any other advantage and it would arguably make your script harder to maintain.

Comment: I see, thank you. I don't see any way to get anything more from the object. I hadn't thought of the regex though! Could give it a go and compare :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case statements are easy to read and maintain.

```
for num in 5 20; do       
  for unit in s m h d; do
    case "$unit" in
    s) echo "seconds ok: $n$u"                                       ;;
    m) if ((num < 15)) then; echo "Min $num < 15 ok: $num$unit" 
       else                  echo "Min 15+, break: $num$unit"        ;;
    *) echo "Time > minutes, break: $num$unit"                       ;;
    esac
  done
done
```

output:

```
seconds ok: 5s
Min 5 < 15 ok: 5m
Time > minutes, break: 5h
Time > minutes, break: 5d
seconds ok: 20s
Min 15+, break: 20m
Time > minutes, break: 20h
Time > minutes, break: 20d
```

A simple `if` structure works too.

```
for num in 5 20; do
  for unit in s m h d; do
    if   [[ s == "$unit" ]]                   ; then echo "seconds ok: $num$unit";     
    elif [[ m == "$unit" ]] && (( num < 15 )) ; then echo "Min $num < 15 ok: $num$unit";
    else                                             echo "Time > 15m: $num$unit";     
    fi
  done
done
```

output:

```
seconds ok: 5s
Min 5 < 15 ok: 5m
Time > 15m: 5h
Time > 15m: 5d
seconds ok: 20s
Time > 15m: 20m
Time > 15m: 20h
Time > 15m: 20d
```

I think unless a regex is pretty complicated you're going to have to break it out into multiple tests anyway, so why not keep it simple?

Comment: This is perfect, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

```sh
#! /bin/bash

makeHorodate () {
    # Initialize counters
    local -i SECONDS=0
    local -i MINUTES=0
    local -i HOURS=0
    local -i DAYS=0
    # Loop on elements
    for ELT in $1; do
        # Remove comas
        ELT=${ELT//,/}
        # Check element format
        [[ ! "${ELT}" =~ ^[0-9]+[smhd]$ ]] && echo "oops. element '${ELT}' not recognized" >&2 && return 1
        # Remove '0'
        while [[ "${ELT:0:1}" == 0 ]]; do ELT=${ELT:1}; done
        [[ "${ELT}" =~ ^[smhd]$ ]] && ELT="0${ELT}"
        # Add values in good counter
        case "${ELT}" in
            *s)
                SECONDS+=${ELT%s}
            ;;
            *m)
                MINUTES+=${ELT%m}
            ;;
            *h)
                HOURS+=${ELT%h}
            ;;
            *d)
                DAYS+=${ELT%d}
            ;;
        esac
    done
    # Format output in a big number
    local RESULT=0
    printf -v RESULT "%d%03d%03d%03d" ${DAYS} ${HOURS} ${MINUTES} ${SECONDS}
    while [[ "${RESULT:0:1}" == 0 ]]; do RESULT=${RESULT:1}; done
    [[ "${RESULT}" == "" ]] && RESULT=0
    echo -n "${RESULT}"
    return 0
}

echo $(makeHorodate "30s, 15m, 3h, 17d")
echo $(makeHorodate "44s, 23m, 17h, 5d")
# with '0'
echo $(makeHorodate "03s, 002m, 01h, 0d")
# different elements order -> same result
echo $(makeHorodate "01h, 002m, 03s, 0d")
# some values
echo $(makeHorodate "3m, 15d")
# just 15 seconds
echo $(makeHorodate "15s")

# now numeric comparisons are possible between any values
if [[ $(makeHorodate "01h, 002m, 03s, 0d") -eq $(makeHorodate "03s, 002m, 01h, 0d") ]]; then
    echo "Equal"
fi
# Test > 15 seconds
if [[ $(makeHorodate "01h, 002m, 03s, 0d") -gt $(makeHorodate "15s") ]]; then
    echo "> 15 seconds"
fi
# Other test for 15 seconds
if [[ $(makeHorodate "01h, 002m, 03s, 0d") -gt 15 ]]; then
    echo "> 15 seconds"
fi
# Test > 3 minutes
if [[ $(makeHorodate "01h, 002m, 03s, 0d") -gt $(makeHorodate "3m") ]]; then
    echo "> 3 minutes"
fi
# Other test > 3 minutes
if [[ $(makeHorodate "01h, 002m, 03s, 0d") -gt 3000 ]]; then
    echo "> 3 minutes"
fi
```

Output:

```
17003015030
5017023044
1002003
1002003
15000003000
15
Equal
> 15 seconds
> 15 seconds
> 3 minutes
> 3 minutes
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string in to value and unit with parameter substitution, then choose a path based on the unit, using `case`:

```
time=15m # eg

val=${time%[a-z]}
unit=${time##*[0-9]}

case $unit in
    s) ;;
    m) ((val>15)) && break;;
    *) break
esac

# keep going..
```

Answer (score 0):

"I think unless a regex is pretty complicated you're going to have to break it out into multiple tests anyway, so why not keep it simple?"
(Paul Hodges)

Here is a simple example for playing around with...
test.txt

```
# 31d, 5h, 45m, 30s, 15m, 3h, 17d

# tgrep function needs 4 arguments: pat1 pat2 pat3 file
tgrep(){ local result=($(grep -o -E "[${1}]{1,1}[${2}]{1,1}[${3}]{1,1}" "${4}"; )); printf "%s\n" "${result[@]}"; return ${#result[@]}; }

# Example: tgrep ' 0-9' '0-9' 'dhms' 'test.txt' && echo "found nothing" || printf "%s\n" "[ ${?} hit(s) ]"
```

It creates an array of matched strings in `result` and return the amount of matches.

Impression: (bash)

```
$ . test.txt # Source the function tgrep (aka include)
$ tgrep ' ' '0-9' 'dhms' 'test.txt' && echo "found nothing" || echo $?
5h
3h
2
$ tgrep '3' '0' 'dhms' 'test.txt' && echo "found nothing" || echo $?
30s
1
$ tgrep '4' '5' 'dhms' 'test.txt' && echo "found nothing" || echo $?
45m
1
$ tgrep '.' '.' '.' 'test.txt' && echo "found nothing" || echo $?

found nothing
# And finally ask how many minutes or seconds are lower than 30
$ tgrep ' 0-2' '0-9' 'ms' 'test.txt' && echo "found nothing" || echo $?
15m
1
```